# The relation between the geodesics of two Riemannian metrics

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I have a Riemannian metric on $R^3$ whose matrix is written as $h=P^TDP$, where $P\in SO(3)$ and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with positive valued smooth functions on the diagonal. Here $SO(3)$ is the special orthogonal space.

To be more clear at each point $p$, $h(p)$ in $T_pM$ is as $h(p)=(P^TDP)(p)$ with $P(p)\in SO(3)$ and $D(p)=diag(a(p),b(p),c(p))$. Also  $P(p)=R_z({\gamma(p)})R_y({\beta(p)})R_x({\alpha(p)})$, where

$$R_x(\alpha(p))=
  \left(\begin{matrix}
  1 &           0 &            0\\
  0 & \cos \alpha(p) & -\sin \alpha(p)\\
  0 & \sin \alpha(p) & \cos \alpha(p)
  \end{matrix}\right),
  R_y(\beta(p))= 
  \left(\begin{matrix}
  \cos \beta(p) & 0&\sin \beta(p) \\
  0 &            1  & 0\\
  -\sin \beta(p) & 0&\cos \beta(p)  
  \end{matrix}\right),$$
$$  \begin{align*}
  R_z(\gamma(p))=
  \left(\begin{matrix}
  \cos \gamma(p) & -\sin \gamma(p) & 0\\
  \sin \gamma(p) & \cos \gamma(p)  & 0\\
  0 &         0  & 1
  \end{matrix}\right).
  \end{align*}$$

> If I am not wrong $D$ is also a Riemannain metric! (Yes?)

Now my question is this:

> There is any relation between the geodesics of $h$ with those of $D$?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: $P$ defines an isometry between $R^3$ with the metric $h$ and $R^3$ with the metric given by $D$, so it carries geodesics to geodesics.

Comment: Here, indeed, we have $h(X,Y)=D(PX,PY)$! right? So given each geodesic $\alpha$ on $R^3$ with metric D, P maps it to a geodesic with respect to h. Now this new geodesic is $P\alpha$?